# Progress Callbacks In RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Started using RxJava and I want to be able to show a progress bar alongside my subscription.

I have a `List` of entities that I emit using `Observable.from`. I want to convert each entity into a `JSONObject` by using an `Observable` in a `flatMap`. See below for code.

```
Observable.from(entities)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Entity, Observable<JSONObject>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<JSONObject> call(Entity entity) {
                    return entityToJSON(entity);
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object o) {
                    // on next
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error: "+throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }, new Action0() { // onComplete
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    // onComplete
                }
            });
```

**My Question**

How do I, during this conversion to JSON return progress updates that I can update my `ProgressDialog` with?

**Possible Solution**

As there is a `ProgressDialog` up, I run this on the main thread and pass the `ProgressDialog` to the `Observable` to update. I believe this would work but I want to stay off the ui thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.doOnNext()
```

For every converted element and change progress bar.

If you want chage multiple times, you need do this on `entityToJSON(entity)` method. But `entityToJSON` works on `Schedulers.io()` thread, and you need use `runOnUiThread` method or `uiHandler` from this method. 
Read more: 
[Accessing views from other thread (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183111/accessing-views-from-other-thread-android) 
Communicating with the UI Thread:  https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: What if I wanted to do it multiple times for one entity? Such as 10% converted and then 20% etc/

Comment: If you want chage multiple times, you need do this on entityToJSON(entity) method. But entityToJSON work on Schedulers.io() thread, and you need use runOnUiThread method or uiHandler from this method. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183111/accessing-views-from-other-thread-android

Comment: Would be useful to have a `subscriber.onProgress(int progress)` callback in the `Subscriber` wouldn't it. Please add the above comment to your answer for completeness